# Bibliography shows citation locations in LyX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

I'm rather new to LaTeX and as a result I'm starting out with LyX.

The problem is that in my bibliography I cannot get rid of the citation locations.

You can see here it sometimes (though not always) starts with (document) and then lists the section/subsection that the citation is located in.

[image]

e.g.

> Part, D. (1984). Reasons and Persons. Oxford: Oxford University Press.
>   (document), 1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 5, 2.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.2, 4.1, 12, 5.2, 5.3

I'm sure this is a really easy fix but I can't find anything to disable this.

This happens with all styles, though I'm currently using [`apa-good`](http://web.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html#reedsty).

Comment: Another philosopher on TeX.sx. Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

> Document > Settings > PDF Properties > Hyperlinks > Backreferences > Off

The default setting is 'section' which causes references in non-sections (e.g. captions, glossary, etc) to be referenced as "(document)" but you can set it to "off", "slide" or "page".

Non-Lyx users may find [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173769/48287) useful.