# bibliography not referencing glossary

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, glossaries

My glossary contains definitions from WiKipedia, which I would like to reference as a quote with a /cite command to my bibliography. 
My bibliography is using hyperrefs to link to the positions within the document, which is very useful when the reader is jumping to the bib and needs to return back to the reading position.
But the hyperrefs within the bibliography do not contain the glossary! At the expected position, it displays '(document)', linking to the first page, but not the glossary.

It seems to me that the bibliography is built first and cannot find the glossary page?
Any help on how to fix this issue? Any help is highly appreciated. :)

I reduced my paper to a small example (miniexample.tex + References.bib), and also attached my output profile exported from TeXnicCenter.
miniexample.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black, menucolor=black, urlcolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, pagebackref=false, backref=section, breaklinks={true}]{hyperref}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newglossaryentry{SWOT}{%
type=\acronymtype,
name={SWOT},%
first={Strength, Weaknesses, Opportunities and Threads (SWOT)},
description={Strength, Weaknesses, Opportunities and Threats\\ SWOT is a structured     planning method used to evaluate the strengths, weaknesses, opportunities, and threats involved in a project or in a business venture~\cite{SWOTWiKiPedia}}%
}
\makeindex
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
any title
\newpage
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\printglossaries
\tableofcontents
\normalsize
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Here i do some test with citation of SWOT~\cite{SWOTWiKiPedia}.

Here i do use gls of \gls{SWOT}. Now i use \gls{SWOT} a second time.
\newpage
Usage of SWOT~\cite{SWOTWiKiPedia} on the next page.
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

References.bib

```
@misc{SWOTWiKiPedia,
    key     = {SWOTWiKiPedia},
    title = {Strengths, Weaknesses, Opportunities, and Threats},
    howpublished    = {Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia \newline \url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWOT_analysis}},
    note    = {\\Accessed: 2014-04-25}
}
```

Using TeXnicCenter with import latex-pdf-glossary+acronym_win7.tco as output profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<txcop:outputProfiles version="2" xmlns:txcop="http://schemas.ToolsCenter.org/TeXnicCenter/OutputProfiles.xsd">
    <outputProfileList>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; PS" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="latex.exe" arguments="-src -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="DviPs" path="dvips.exe" arguments="&quot;%Bm.dvi&quot;" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; DVI" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="latex.exe" arguments="-src -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors/>
            <viewer path="yap.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="yap.exe" arguments="-1 &quot;%bm.dvi&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="yap.exe" arguments="-1 -s %l&quot;%Wc&quot; &quot;%bm.dvi&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LuaLaTeX &#8680; PDF" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="lualatex.exe" arguments="-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors/>
            <viewer path="miktex-texworks.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments=" &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments="  &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; PS &#8680; PDF" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="latex.exe" arguments="-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="DviPs (PDF)" path="dvips.exe" arguments="-P pdf &quot;%Bm.dvi&quot;" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
                <processor name="ps2pdf" path="ps2pdf.exe" arguments="&quot;%bm.ps&quot;" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="miktex-texworks.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments=" &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments="  &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="XeLaTeX &#8680; PDF" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="xelatex.exe" arguments="-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors/>
            <viewer path="miktex-texworks.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments=" &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments="  &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; PDF" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="pdflatex.exe" arguments="-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors/>
            <viewer path="AcroRd32.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="true">
                <viewProjectCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" arguments=" &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)][FileOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" arguments="  &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)][FileOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocClose(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; PDF (Glossary+Acronym)" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="pdflatex.exe" arguments="-interaction=nonstopmode -max-print-line=120 &quot;%pm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="makeglossaries #1" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="-s &quot;%tm&quot;.ist -t &quot;%tm&quot;.glg -o &quot;%tm&quot;.gls &quot;%tm&quot;.glo" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
                <processor name="makeacronyms #1" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="-s &quot;%tm&quot;.ist -t &quot;%tm&quot;.alg -o &quot;%tm&quot;.acr &quot;%tm&quot;.acn" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
                <processor name="pdflatex #2" path="pdflatex.exe" arguments="-interaction=nonstopmode -max-print-line=120 &quot;%pm&quot;" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
                <processor name="makeglossaries #2" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="-s &quot;%tm&quot;.ist -t &quot;%tm&quot;.glg -o &quot;%tm&quot;.gls &quot;%tm&quot;.glo" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
                <processor name="makeacronyms #2" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="-s &quot;%tm&quot;.ist -t &quot;%tm&quot;.alg -o &quot;%tm&quot;.acr &quot;%tm&quot;.acn" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
                <processor name="pdflatex #3" path="pdflatex.exe" arguments="-interaction=nonstopmode -max-print-line=120 &quot;%pm&quot;" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="AcroRd32.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="true">
                <viewProjectCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)][FileOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)][FileOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="acroview" topic="control" command="[DocClose(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; DVI &#8680; PDF" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="latex.exe" arguments="-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm.idx&quot; -t &quot;%tm.ilg&quot; -o &quot;%tm.ind&quot;"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="dvipdfm" path="dvipdfm.exe" arguments="&quot;%bm.dvi&quot;" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="miktex-texworks.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments=" &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="miktex-texworks.exe" arguments="  &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX &#8680; PDF (with glossaries)" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="true" path="pdflatex.exe" arguments="-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode &quot;%wm&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="true" path="bibtex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;"/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="true" path="makeindex.exe" arguments="&quot;%tm&quot;.glo -t &quot;%tm&quot;.glg -s &quot;%tm&quot;.ist -o &quot;%tm&quot;.gls"/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors/>
            <viewer path="AcroRd32.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="true">
                <viewProjectCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" arguments=" &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)][FileOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" arguments="  &quot;%bm.pdf&quot;"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="AcroRd32.exe" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)][FileOpen(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="dde">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="acroviewR11" topic="control" command="[DocClose(&quot;%bm.pdf&quot;)]"/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
    </outputProfileList>
</txcop:outputProfiles>
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! That example is not really *minimal*. Do you need all of those packages to reproduce the problem? Also, please reformat your code by indenting it by 4 spaces. Easy way to do this: highlight the lot and click the `{}` button on the edit bar. Plus, either delete the empty lines or post something which contains something other than blocks of grey. EDIT: I've fixed these issues on this post. Press 'edit' to see how to format code correctly for the future. And always check a post isn't mostly blank before abandoning it to its fate!

Answer (score 1):

Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,

it seems to be located to the

```
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black, menucolor=black, urlcolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, pagebackref=false, breaklinks={true}, backref=section]{hyperref}
```

exactly the backref=section. Glossary seems to not count as section and then creates (document) directing to the first page of the document.

I chose backref=page to resolve this for my paper. Options for backref are:

```
backref=page,   % activate back references inside bibliography (section, slide, page, none)
```

This now addes the Roman page number to the bibliography as back reference.

I wish you a pleasent time with TeX!